# JQuery select an element that appears after submit

Tags: jquery, forms, dom

I have an issue that's been bugging me for some time now. It's a form that is returning inconsistent error messages. The checkboxes on the form, as default, aren't mandatory so I've forced them to be with the following code:

```
$(function() {
 var q = $("input[name='field_1']");     
  if (!$(q).is(':checked')) {                
   $(q).prop('required', true);     
 }           
});
```

The problem comes next, there is a hidden class `.error` which grabs the name of the field (for example first name) and then appends 'is required' to this, and so results in a user friendly error message. This class, which only appears on the DOM upon submitting the form, does not seem to like checkboxes - I believe this is because it has nothing to put in front of 'is required'.

Here is a snapshot of what it looks like.

```
<div class="comp_class" >
<label class='label_1 '>Competition</label>
<div class="control_1">
    <div class="checkbox"><label><input type='checkbox' name='field_1' value='Yes' required class ="error"/> Yes</label>
    <label for="field_1" class="error"> is required.</label>
    "Yes"
```

With the simpler fields such as first name the error class grabs the field name from the HTML contained within `label_1`, this pulled in front of the 'is required'. The other fields are made mandatory by default and the frustrating part of this is that I can't have access to the HTML, otherwise this would be extremely simple, and so why I am trying to use jQuery to access and manipulate the content.

I tried something like (amongst many other things!) -

```
$('#submit_button').click(function(){
 $('.error').html("<p>This field is required</p>")
});
```

If anyone has any suggestions please send them my way.

Comment: So to clarify, the `<label for="field_1" class="error"> is required.</label>` appears after submit? It is not part of the dom beforehand? Also, the `.error` class is on both the label and the checkbox...

Comment: Yes that's correct it only appears after submit. Yeah I'm not sure why that is, as I mentioned I can't access/control the structure of the HTML itself.

Comment: Unrelated but why making your var a jquery object -> `$(q)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created some sample code to test checkBox in your test case:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit_button').click(function() {
    checkBox();
  });

  function checkBox() {
    var $q = $("input[name='field_1']");
    if (!$q.is(':checked')) {
      $('.error').html("<p>This field is required</p>")
      $q.prop('checked', true);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="comp_class">
  <label class='label_1 '>Competition</label>
  <div class="control_1">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type='checkbox' name='field_1' value='Yes' required />Do you agree?</label>
      <label for="field_1" class="error"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id='submit_button'>Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly my thoughts! What's up with the variable turning into a jquery object later

Comment: Please excuse my lack of well formed jQuery as you can probably tell I'm quite new to it. I will try your suggestion now, many thanks.

Comment: Okay so this is still returning the same results, any other ideas?

Comment: Many thanks for that @Max Zoom I will pick this up again once I'm back at my computer. Thanks again your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry it took ages to accept. It turned out to be a Wordpress specific error that was disallowing the use of $, so any correct code was being labelled incorrect. Thanks again.